# connect() function taking too long

Tags: c, linux, unix, networking, tcp

When I type in to the terminal:

```
echo "GET /" | ./<executable name> www.google.com <port number, usually 80>
```

the terminal just sits there like it's waiting for input or it's stuck in an infinite loop. What is happening is that connection is taking too long I think.

```
  /*Creating socket*/
  int sock = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock < 0) {
    printf("error creating socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("1\n");
  /*Establish connection to the echo server*/
  int r = connect(sock, addrList->ai_addr, addrList->ai_addrlen);
  printf("1.5\n");
  if (r < 0) {
    perror("Connection failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("2\n");
```

Here, the 1 prints out, but the 1.5 right after the connect doesn't print out and the terminal just sits.

This problem didn't happen before and I used to get the page's source code back instantly. But now this problem is occurring.

It started occurring after I typed in to the terminal: `netstat -an -A inet | grep :2525`

so this may have had an effect.

Here is the entire code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  if (argc != 3) {
    printf("Invalid arguments\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  char *serverIP = argv[1]; /*Server hostname*/
  char *portNumber = argv[2]; /*Port Number*/
  void *numericAddress;
  char addrBuffer[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
  in_port_t port;
  char buffer_stdin[65535];
  char buffer_stdout[65535];
  int bytes_read = 0;
  int bytes_written = 0;

  /*getting integral number of string representation of port number*/
  in_port_t servPort = atoi(argv[2]);

  /*------------------get binary number of hostname-----------------*/
  struct addrinfo addrCriteria;
  memset(&addrCriteria, 0, sizeof(addrCriteria));
  addrCriteria.ai_family = AF_INET;
  addrCriteria.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
  addrCriteria.ai_protocol = IPPROTO_TCP;

  struct addrinfo *addrList;

  int rtnVal = getaddrinfo(serverIP, portNumber, &addrCriteria, &addrList);
  if (rtnVal != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo() failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  numericAddress = &((struct sockaddr_in *) (addrList->ai_addr))->sin_addr;
  /*Converting port to binary*/
  ((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrList->ai_addr))->sin_port = htonl(servPort);
  /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

  inet_ntop(addrList->ai_addr->sa_family, numericAddress, addrBuffer, sizeof(addrBuffer));
  printf("IP ADDRESS: %s\n", addrBuffer);

  /*Creating socket*/
  int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
  if (sock < 0) {
    printf("error creating socket\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  /*printf("1\n");*/
  /*Establish connection to the echo server*/
  int r = connect(sock, addrList->ai_addr, addrList->ai_addrlen);
  printf("%d\n", r);
  if (r < 0) {
    perror("Connection failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("2\n");
  /*Reading from stdin and writing to socket until stdin ends
    bytes_read = read(0, buffer_stdin, sizeof(buffer_stdin));
    write(sock, buffer_stdin, bytes_read);*/

  while ((bytes_read = read(0, buffer_stdin, sizeof(buffer_stdin)-1)) > 0) {
    write(sock, buffer_stdin, bytes_read);
  }

  /*Shutting down write end of socket*/
  int r_shutdown = shutdown(sock, SHUT_WR);
  if (r_shutdown < 0) {
    printf("Shutting down write end of socket failed\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  /*Reading from socket and writing to stdout until socket ends*/
  while ((bytes_read = read(sock, buffer_stdout, sizeof(buffer_stdout)-1)) > 0) {
    write(1, buffer_stdout, bytes_read);
  }

  close(sock);
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: netstat won't have an effect. It shows stats, doesn't change things.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code, can you post the entire thing?

Comment: It is hard to tell why the syscall blocks for so long. Do you have way of monitoring traffic at you PC like wireshark or TCPdump? It would be good to know if the actual SYN-packet is sent as soon as the systemcall is invoked, and if there is delay between the received SYN,ACK and the return of the system call. Some context on the addrList would also help

Comment: You need to check he return value immediately, and call perror() before calling any other system calls, such as the write() implied by the printf(). Otherwise you'll get the wrong  error message.

Comment: @midor no I don't have that kind of software. Look at edit above to see full code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nvm I figured it out.

Apparently I had to take into account big endian vs little endian, and so in this line:

```
((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrList->ai_addr))->sin_port = htonl(servPort);
```

the htonl should've been htons, so:

```
((struct sockaddr_in *)(addrList->ai_addr))->sin_port = htons(servPort);
```

Comment: servPort was already supplied to getaddrinfo so it should already be filled in the address field.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do it is :

```
struct sockaddr_in address;
sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if(sockfd!=-1)
  {
          perror("socket :");
          printf("sockfd = %d\n", sockfd);
  }
  else
  {
          perror("socket");
          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  address.sin_family = AF_INET;
  address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
  address.sin_port = htons(9734);
  len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

  result = connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&address, len);
```